# Python list being appended when not (directly) referenced

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Okay so this is just a rough bit of code I made when trying to make a Guess Who(TM)  for class challenge and I wanted to make a random character generator function (its only a proof of concept and I would expand it complexity later! Please don't judge!). However the character's template feature list seems to be appended every iteration (and so skewing my other loops) when it aught not to. It should be adding an item to the end of each new generated list - not the template. Yet the template variable is not appended to in the code, only a temporary copy is/should be. Here's the code:

```
tempfeatures = characters = []
for i in range(len(characternames)):
    tempfeatures = []
    charactername = characternames[random.randint(0,len(characternames)-1)]
    characternames.remove(charactername)
    a = features
    tempfeatures = a
    ### "Debug bit" ###
    print(features)
    print("loooooop")
    for y in range(len(features)):
        print(len(features))
        temp = random.randint(0,1)
        if temp == 1:
            tempfeatures[y][1] = True
        else:
            tempfeatures[y][1] = False
    tempfeatures.append(["Dead",True])
    characters.append([charactername,tempfeatures])
print(characters)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you initializing `tempfeatures` twice? Once in `tempfeatures = characters = []` and then in `tempfeatures = []`. Your question is unclear. You are using lots of statements in your question without explaining which variables you are referring to. There is no `template` variable in your code and you are just writing "template" in your question. Explain more clearly or else it's difficult to get answers for unclear questions

Comment: ...and what is the point of writing `a = features`, `tempfeatures = a` instead of `tempfeatures = features`? We also don't know what is `characternames`.

Comment: also `tempfeatures = characters = []` doesn't do what you think it does, unless you are wanting `tempfeatures` and `characters` to point to the same list.

Comment: Post a proper MCVE if you hope to get any help.

Comment: Bazingaa, because I the tempfeatures list is edited randomly, but has to be cleared for the next character's feature randomisation.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the tempfeature variable is "call by reference" and not "call by value". - thanks python.

So when duplicating lists, one must use this on the end of the variable name

```
tempfeature = feature[:]
```

(the **[:]** bit)

Thanks all for your comments!

Answer (score 0):

This is called a **shallow** copy, it just referenciates the list to another variable, as seen here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html
You need to make and intependent copy, or a **deep** copy, as: `tempfeature = list(feature)` so changing `tempfeature` won't interfere with `feature`